# Can Spring Android RestTemplate return a List?

Tags: android, json, spring

I currently have the following code in my android project:

```
protected List<Facility> doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(<SomeWebService>);
            httpGet.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            try{
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Facility>>(){}.getType();
                List<Facility> facilities= gson.fromJson(httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler), collectionType);
                return facilities;
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

In Looking into Spring-Android's RestTemplate, I see no way to turn a JSON Array into a List (in this case Facility)   Everything I googled points me to an object. I was looking to see if using Spring-Android would make the above code simpler/cleaner, but haven't seen anything that gives me any idea.  How would one write the above code with Spring Android, specifically getting me a list back from the template?

Answer (score 4):

Because the generic information is not aviable at runtime you need this trick: create a subclass of `List<Facility>` to make it avaiable

```
public static class FacilityList extends ArrayList<Facility>{
}

...

FacilityListfacilities= gson.fromJson(
    httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler),
    FacilityList.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be to retrieve the List as an Array and then convert it:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Facility[]>(){}.getType();
Facility[] facilities= gson.fromJson(httpClient.execute(httpGet, responseHandler), collectionType);
return Arrays.asList(facilities);
```